# Stata: Generate new variable with all values (e.g. not just max or min) for a group based on other variable in the group

Tags: stata

I want to create new variables for the group country (iso_o/iso_d) with characteristics of the variable indepdate.

So far I have been typing:

```
gen include=1 if heg_o != 1 
egen iso_o_indepdate1=min(indepdate * include), by(iso_o)
egen iso_o_indepdate2=max(indepdate * include), by(iso_o)
replace iso_o_indepdate2=. if iso_o_indepdate1==iso_o_indepdate2
drop include
*
gen include=1 if heg_d !=1 
egen iso_d_indepdate1=min(indepdate * include), by(iso_d)
egen iso_d_indepdate2=max(indepdate * include), by(iso_d)
replace iso_d_indepdate2=. if iso_d_indepdate1==iso_d_indepdate2
drop include
```

The problem is I can use `min()` and `max()` combined to create two new variables for the values within `indepdate`, but if there are more then three I haven't been able to get a solution. Here a small table.

```
iso_o   group  indepdate   new1    new2    new3
FRA      1      1960       1960    1980    1999
FRA      1      1980       1960    1980    1999
FRA      1      1999       1960    1980    1999
FRA      1      .          1960    1980    1999
USA      2      1955       1955     .       .
USA      2      .          1955     .       .
USA      2      .          1955     .       .
```

So for this small example I could try work with intervals, however the dataset is very large and therefore I cannot tell for sure how many values are in one interval.

Any hint on another approach for this?

Comment: This is unclear to me. Why `by(iso_d)`; is that a typo? What do you want to calculate that you can't?

Comment: No typo. I'm working with panel data on trade flows. I need the info of the independence date of `iso_d` (destinated country), too. For example if you have the year 1960 and country A `iso_o` and B `iso_d`. A is independant for 4 years (year of independence=1956)  and B two years (year od independence=1958), the dummy for four years and also two years will turn on in order to observe the effects of trade the years subsequent colonial independence. Therefore I need to kinda spread the info of `indepdate` to other groupings, seperately for `iso_o` and `iso_d`. Hope this makes it clearer now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `reshape` and then `merge`:

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data ---

input ///
str3 iso_o   group  indepdate   new1    new2    new3
FRA      1      1960       1960    1980    1999
FRA      1      1980       1960    1980    1999
FRA      1      1999       1960    1980    1999
FRA      1      .          1960    1980    1999
USA      2      1955       1955     .       .
USA      2      .          1955     .       .
USA      2      .          1955     .       .
end

drop new*

list, sepby(group)

tempfile orig
save "`orig'"

*----- what you want -----

bysort group (indepdate) : gen j = _n 

reshape wide indepdate, i(group) j(j)
keep group indepdate*

merge 1:m group using "`orig'", assert(match) nogenerate

// list
sort group indepdate
order iso_o group indepdate indepdate*
list, sepby(group)
```

See `help dropmiss` to drop variables that have only missing values.

But the bigger question is why do you want to do this?

Comment: Thank you Roberto for the edit and the answer! This helped a lot!

Comment: To explain why: `indepdate` is the year of independence of a colony. `iso_o` is the origin country and `iso_d` the destinated country for trade. I want to generate dummies for the years after independence to observe their effects. For colony-metropole, trade between siblings (same colonizer) and rest of the world. In the data I was given `indepdate` is just given for colony metropole trade but not the other groupings. Also a country can be colonized more then once. So this approach therefore made sense for me. Hope this explains the intention!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You can [upvote/accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find it useful. Doing this, you will increase both our reputations.